# Add "Everyone except external users" to sharepoint visitors group using powershell CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom, everyone

I want to  add `Everyone except external users` group to SharePoint visitors group  using powershell CSOM.

I googled it but didnt find correct script.

Can anyone help me in this?

Please respond ASAP.

TIA

Comment: Is "Everyone except external users" group an AD group or SharePoint group? 
I don't think you can use powershell and CSOM both.

Comment: Sharepoint group

Comment: You cannot add any SharePoint group to another SharePoint group.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add any SharePoint group to another SharePoint group.

However, you can add an AD group  into a SharePoint group or directly add users in the SharePoint group.